# Import a file like a model in python?

Tags: python-2.7, path, pickle, python-import

An object has been serialized by pickle, and it will be used by a model which would be placed at anyplace (under any directory). Since the object is frequently used and kind of a part of the model, I want to have the model contain the pickle file (place the file under a directory of the model) as a variable.

./data/constant.py
`object = pickle.load(open('object.pkl'))`
 
./data/object.pkl

./code/model01.py

```
from ..data import constant 
# or
# from __future import absolute_import 
# from model.data import constant
object = constant.object
```

./code/model02.py
`from ..data import constant
object = constant.object`

The problem is obviously that python will search `object.pkl` under `./code/`(and anywhere I use the function of the model outside of the model) rather than `./data/`.

Am I doing it right? Any better solutions? Thanks. 
I think this question may be duplicated (this is a very common issue) but I cannot find any related archive here. If so, please help redirect me there.

Comment: Then why not simply pass `open` the full path?

Comment: Yes, that's because, as mentioned, the module can be placed anywhere... So the full path is not certain.

Comment: I don't see any way that the calling code can 'guess' where the pickle file will be placed. My suggestion is to store it in a predefined location (may be even configurable) which will be known to all calling codes.

Comment: But I thought if it could be placed in a relative path it would be better(and under the directory of the model). The pickled file acts just like a string or whatnot. Should I bother configuring? If that's the only way to tackle it, Okay, point taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a little bit of path manipulation should work:

In module `constant.py`:

```
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
obj = pickle.load(open(os.path.join(path, 'object.pkl')))
```

Comment: Yeh, it works fine. I'm wondering if I can use the python resource manager for such issues.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want `object` to be part of the module `constant`.

One way would be just putting the pickled object in `constant.py`:

```
my_object = pickle.loads(pickled_object)  # don't use the name `object` it is a built-in
```

Note the `s` in `loads`.

`pickled_object` needs to be placed inside `constant.py` before the line shown above. It has to be a byte string.
You can create it either directly from the object:

```
pickled_object = pickle.dumps(obj)
```

or take it form the pickled file and past it in.

#### Example

Pickle your object:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> obj = [1, 2, 3]
>>> pickle.dumps(obj)
b'\x80\x03]q\x00(K\x01K\x02K\x03e.'
```

Now, in `constant.py`:

```
pickled_object = b'\x80\x03]q\x00(K\x01K\x02K\x03e.'
my_object = pickle.loads(pickled_object)
```

As a result, `my_object` is `[1, 2, 3]` and can be accessed via `constant.my_object`